# ISBLANK() function

Tags: formulas, google-sheets

**Is there any way I can check whether a cell is empty?**

There is a function `ISBLANK()` but it returns **false** when there's a formula in a cell even thought the formula doesn't return anything (or an empty string).

I would like it to return **true** when the formula doesn't return anything as well. So the cell seems to be empty without any value.

Answer (score 47, accepted):

You can check whether a cell is empty or not by using the following formula:

```
=if(C2="";"The cell is empty";"The cell is not empty")
```

Comment: Thanks. This one is simpler than mine. It was obviously too trivial for me to think of it. :)

Comment: I believe the real answer is actually to fix the original formula in the cell being tested. I suggest the formula is not actually returning an empty string.  Place this formula in cell A1:  `=if(1=1,"","No Way")` and it puts a value into the cell.  Unlike Excel, place this one in cell A2: `=if(1=1, ,"No Way")` and it will leave the cell blank. This is easily tested by placing these formulas in 2 other cells: `=ISBLANK(A1)` will return FALSE while `=ISBLANK(A2)` will return TRUE.  Likewise `=ISBLANK(if(1=1, ,"No Way"))` return TRUE.

Comment: Wouldn't it just be `C2=""`?

Answer (score 9):

I can use function

```
=IF(COUNTBLANK(cell:cell)=1;"Blank cell";"Not blank")
```

that will be one only of the `cell` is empty.

Answer (score 5):

I found the function `LEN(A1)` to be very useful and robust. It also works for cells that contained text that has been deleted. It returns the length of a cell's content and if it returns 0, the cell is empty.

- `IF(NOT(LEN(A1)))` or `IF(LEN(A1)=0)` to check for empty cells
- `IF(LEN(A1))` or `IF(LEN(A1)<>0)` to check for non-empty cells

I prefer the fist variant because it's easier to read. The number 0 evaluates to `FALSE` in a boolean check, any positive number evaluates to `TRUE`.

Answer (score 3):

You can wrap the `ISBLANK()` with a `NOT()` it basically switches what ever is in it to the opposite of its original result.

> =NOT(ISBLANK(A2))

Its checking if `A2` is not empty. If it has something in `A2` it will give a `True` result.

[NOT - Docs editors Help](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093305)

Comment: How does that help anything?  The OP was asking how to determine if a cell is blank which was defined as empty or containing an empty string.

Comment: This is the best answer. It's simple and to the point. The OP asked how to CHECK and this does exactly that!

Answer (score 3):

Except for @Martin Hansen's A (where all four versions return nothing but `#N/A` for me) two of the above As do distinguish:

```
a "blank" cell (truly blank OR containing a formula returning `""`)
```

from

```
a "non-blank" cell (whether Text, Numeric, Boolean or other Formula).
```

They are all however much longer than they need to be if just for the purpose of differentiation. Much of the length is due to  the text chosen to notify the condition. Such text is not necessary (*I would like it to return **true**...*). A correct A to *Is the cell "not-blank"* would serve for differentiation (as @CamSyl's interpretation).

However in that case a correct A to *Is the cell "blank"* would serve equally well (or better, given OP wants `true` for blank), and that can be achieved with a formula roughly a third of the length of @CamSyl's solution (which does not solve OP's problem anyway).

I recommend a formula of the type:

```
=A3=""
```

(which is all the essence of @Mehper C. Palavuzlar's A without the text).

[image: WA16754]

Answer (score 2):

I've searched the internet (Google, search tools, custom range) for references of the `ISBLANK` function pre-dating the OP's question. The `ISBLANK` function already existed during the time of asking: [ISBLANK reference before 01/12/2009](http://productforums.google.com/forum/#!msg/docs/-vzQdCktfjY/r9xdVi4nM7EJ)

Therefore this function will suffice:

```
=IF(ISBLANK(A2)=TRUE;"Blank cell";"Not blank")
```

There is however one thing to take in consideration:

- Deleted text, formatted as *plain text*, isn't empty

Comment: Adding some more explanation as to why this answers the question would help.

Comment: I've already described the problem with `isblank()` function in my question. It only returns `true` when cell is **actually** empty (not having a formula in it either). What I was looking for **no content cells** if that makes it more clear to you.

Comment: If you add `IFERROR(1/0)` it will return TRUE.

Comment: @RobertKoritnik Forgot to mention you.

Comment: @JacobJanTuinstra: Include it where? Division by 0 is always error.

Comment: I was referring to your statement: "I would like it to return true when the formula doesn't return anything as well". I wanted to point out that adding a formula, would return TRUE.

Comment: @RobertKoritnik Forgot to mention you.